# How to prevent the mouse click event from happening when the button is Disabled

Tags: qt

I want to disable the click event for a QPushbutton when it is disabled, whether it can be done ?

Comment: You could achieve that either by subclassing `QPushButton` and installing an `eventFilter` on your custom class, or adding an even filter to the widget that contains your `QPushButton`.

Comment: If the button is disabled, the click events will have no effects. So, you should not have to discard them. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: even if the push button is disabled the click signal is being generated and the function are performed thats why i am asking for a solution